Planetary Gears allowing all gears to move (not holding any gears fixed)
I'm having trouble understanding a more complicated scenario with a planetary gear set. Everywhere I look online I only find examples where one of the gears (sun, planet, ring) is held fixed and the other gears are analysed.
I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction as to what would happen if you apply a torque to one of the gears, and allow the other two gears to spin freely (each with their own inertia). How is the torque apportioned between the two load paths.
Is this even a deterministic system?
Thanks
